# Android webview JavaScript loadurl set variable sdk 24+ issue Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, android, webview, google-analytics

In my App I need to set a JavaScript variable on webviews for tracking purposes that the javascript will use for keeping the native analytics tracking and web tracking synced. It currently is working when I have compiledSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion set to 23.

In `OnPageStarted` I have this code.

```
String javaScript = String.format("javascript: var clientId = '%s';", nativeClientId);
webView.loadUrl(javaScript);
```

When I increase the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 24, this no longer works. Javascript says the variable is not defined. When I set the versions back to 23, it works again.

I found in the WebView docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String, android.webkit.ValueCallback)

> Compatibility note. Applications targeting N or later, JavaScript 
>   state from an empty WebView is no longer persisted across navigations like loadUrl(String). For example, global variables and functions defined before calling loadUrl(String) will not exist in the loaded page. Applications should use addJavascriptInterface(Object, String) instead to persist JavaScript objects across navigations.

How can I convert my javascript to use `AddJavascriptInterface` to set this clientId so that the JavaScript can still read the variable without having to change the web code?

Any suggestions or other ideas would help greatly!

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `onPageStarted()` versus `onPageFinished()`? When is `clientId` read? You could switch to `addJavascriptInterface()`, but that has its own problems, including needing to change all your JavaScript code (changing `clientId` references to something else). Is that practical in your case? Also, have you tried switching to `evaluateJavascript()`, in case this is a `loadUrl()` limitation?

Comment: The clientId is being read in javascript on the page and `OnPageFinished()` was past the time it needed to be set. I tried `evaluteJavascript()` and it works at 23, but again when `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 24 it also stops working.

Comment: And yes the JavaScript code on the page cannot be changed, so I was trying to find a way to set the JavaScript variable and 
didn't know if there way a way with `addJavascriptInterface()`

Comment: "And yes the JavaScript code on the page cannot be changed" -- then I suspect that you will have to keep your `targetSdkVersion` to be 23, until that can get fixed. Whether you use `addJavascriptInterface()`, `WebMessage`, or `WebMessagePort`, you cannot set a `clientId` global from outside the `WebView`.