# Injecting javascript using LoadUrl fails in Android WebView for SDK 24+

Tags: javascript, android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.android

I am trying to inject a javascript namespace with function from App to Android WebView

**NOTE:** I do not have any control on the actual source being loaded on WebView apart from the below script. I am working in Xamarin so the Android code is C#

So there are two major components that I am using:

```
(function() {
    console.log("Loading JS Bindings");
    function addOnClickHandler () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (window.InjectedNamespace) { // check InjectedNamespace namespace exists
                var onClickHandler = window.InjectedNamespace.handleOnClick;
                if (typeof onClickHandler === 'function') {
                    $(":button, a").each(function (idx) {
                        $(this).click(function() {
                            onClickHandler("click!");
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    console.error('missing onclick handler');
                }
            } else {
                console.error('missing InjectedNamespace namespace');
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

1. Above script which will be added by the third-party, which will attach `click` function to all `<button>` and `<a>` tags.
2. Below namespace will be injected from the App side

`var InjectedNamespace={handleOnClick:function(a){Internal.handleOnClickEvent(a)}};`

On App side I have this Javascript interface object

```
class JSInterfaceObject : Java.Lang.Object
    {
      readonly CustomWebView View;
      string Data;

      public JSInterfaceObject(CustomWebView view)
      {
        View = view;
      }

      [Export]
      [JavascriptInterface]
      // only methods exposed with annotation [JavascriptInterface] are exposed to javascript
      public void handleOnClickEvent(string data)
      {
        Log.ForContext("TAG", TAG).Debug("handleOnClickEvent: " + data);
        if(View.OnClick != null)
        {
          View.OnClick(data);
        }
      }
    }
```

And this interface is added to webview using

`AddJavascriptInterface(new JSInterfaceObject(this), "Internal");`

And in `OnPageStarted` I am injecting the javascript using

`webview.LoadUrl("javascript:"+"var IM={handleOnClick:function(a){Internal.handleOnClickEvent(a)}};");`

This setup work fine for Android SDK < 24. But for Webview in SDK >=24 the script always errors out with `missing InjectedNamespace namespace`, which implies the `LoadUrl` in `OnPageStarted` failed!

This check is done in `$(document).ready` in the script.

I found this note in "[Android 7.0 for Developers](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#webview)" which says

> "Starting with apps targeting Android 7.0, the Javascript context will
>   be reset when a new page is loaded. Currently, the context is carried
>   over for the first page loaded in a new WebView instance.
>
> Developers looking to inject Javascript into the WebView should
>   execute the script after the page has started to load."

So tried to add the javascript injection code after the page started loading but got the same error. Also tried using the `WebView.EvaluateJavascript()` but error persists.

The error disappers if I change my TargetSDK to <=23.

Comment: You could read this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44031298/android-webview-javascript-loadurl-set-variable-sdk-24-issue-google-analytics?rq=1

Comment: @YorkShen thanks for the link but not particularly usually to my case as suggested options i.e. decrement `compileSdk` is not really possible (product requirements).